# Загрузка процессора показывает не точный результат

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
    int GetCpuUsage()
{
    static ULARGE_INTEGER TimeIdle, TimeKernel, TimeUser;
    FILETIME Idle, Kernel, User;
    ULARGE_INTEGER uIdle, uKernel, uUser;
    GetSystemTimes(&Idle, &Kernel, &User);
    memcpy(&uIdle, &Idle, sizeof(FILETIME));
    memcpy(&uKernel, &Kernel, sizeof(FILETIME));
    memcpy(&uUser, &User, sizeof(FILETIME));
    long long t;
    t = (((((uKernel.QuadPart - TimeKernel.QuadPart) + (uUser.QuadPart - TimeUser.QuadPart)) -
        (uIdle.QuadPart - TimeIdle.QuadPart))*(100)) / ((uKernel.QuadPart -
            TimeKernel.QuadPart) + (uUser.QuadPart - TimeUser.QuadPart)));
    TimeIdle.QuadPart = uIdle.QuadPart;
    TimeUser.QuadPart = uUser.QuadPart;
    TimeKernel.QuadPart = uKernel.QuadPart;
    return(static_cast<int>(t));
}
```

Когда его первый раз вызываешь, к примеру cout << GetCpuUsage << endl;, то он первое значение всегда показывает 33%, а второе и последующее значение правильно, почти как в диспетчере задач. В чем проблема???

Comment: Не используйте неинициализированные переменные. Особенно в случае статических переменных.

Comment: А вы верите диспетчеру задач? (более общо -- статистике ОС)